# DC-DC variable resistor's side

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, texas-instruments

I plan make DC-DC mini-PCB PCB [like it](https://www.aerial.net/shop/product/161_193/2173/tps54332-dcdc-35v24v-to.html). In my schematic [image: dc-dc variable resistor in High side image] I want regulate output voltage. Because of it I made R1 as variable resistor. In my schematic I am afraid that middle pin of variable resistor can disconnect because of mechanical problems; in this case R1 = 20 kΩ, V<sub>out</sub> =(20000 / 2200 + 1) × 0.8 = 8 V -> damage 5 V load (X1).
Does my schematic look OK or should I make R1 as resistor and R3 as variable resistor?

Comment: Disconnecting middle pin of R1 is equal to upper position. If you afraid of that output voltage, redesign your circuit, increase value of R3.

Answer (score 2):

> *I am afraid that middle pin of variable resistor can disconnect
> because of mechanical problems; in this case R1 = 20 kΩ, Vout =(20000
> / 2200 + 1) × 0.8 = 8 V -> damage 5 V load (X1)*

If you make R3 as a variable resistor then, if the wiper fails, the output voltage can only reduce.

Comment: But I saw a lot of schematic where R1 is variable, [why](https://www.codrey.com/learn/lm2596s-module-a-trivial-tale/) people [do it](https://dzen.ru/media/viktorsochi/tri-prichiny-polomki-ponijaiuscih-i-povyshaiuscih-impulsnyh-preobrazovatelei-ustraniaem-na-primere-lm25116-5fda54ea602c783027c356fd?utm_referer=www.youtube.com)?

Comment: I expect because they haven't analysed the repercussions or, they have chosen a potentiometer of higher than standard quality. Or, the modules do have problems and shouldn't really be bought by anyone who cares too much. @АндрейТернити